# Store Perl CGI Scripts in any directory

Tags: apache, perl, cgi

Is it possible to store perl scripts in any location like out side of the cgi-bin.
I would like to store them in my www folder instead or any folder under the www folder for viewing via browser e.g. (domain.com/index.pl) and not just limited to (domain.com/cgi-bin/index.pl)

Comment: Modern Perl web development tends to use [PSGI/Plack](http://plackperl.org/) rather than CGI.

Answer (score 2):

You can store them in any directory you have [configured](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/cgi.html) Apache to execute CGI scripts in.

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
```

You can also use features such as [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) or [alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) to map a URL on to something in the cgi-bin

Comment: Thanks for replying. I think for the most part I have set the correct settings in the httpd.conf but the odd thing is I get 403 at the root level www but not in sub-domain. Maybe it's in the vhost.conf that is causing the 403 at the root level?